Как добавить stm32 и j-link в platformIO?
Как мне добавить stm32f103c8t6 вместе с программатором j-link в platformIO? У меня есть плата blue-pill, при подключении через micro usb, в диспетчере устройств пишется неизвестное устройство, ошибка запроса дескриптора. При подключении через j-link он определяется как программатор, но я не знаю как добавить его в platformio и загрузить через него прошивку.

RTFM: https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/plus/debug-tools/jlink.html
